# Flutter Two Plugins have same class name defined

Tags: flutter, stripe-payments, jitsi-meet

I;m trying to use JITSI and STRIP in my Flutter Application. But when I run I get the following issue.
How to solve this.

**stripe_payment: ^1.0.9**

**jitsi_meet: ^2.0.0**

C:\Users\nifal.nizar.gradle\caches\transforms-2\files-2.1\ec6fd3efd2e7f7ffe17741b46caf6e74\jetified-react-native-0.61.5-jitsi.2-runtime.jar: R8: Type com.facebook.react.bridge.ReactMethod is defined multiple times: C:\Users\nifal.nizar.gradle\caches\transforms-2\files-2.1\ec6fd3efd2e7f7ffe17741b46caf6e74\jetified-react-native-0.61.5-jitsi.2-runtime.jar:com/facebook/react/bridge/ReactMethod.class, C:\Projects\Medoment.Mobile\build\stripe_payment\intermediates\runtime_library_classes\release\classes.jar:com/facebook/react/bridge/ReactMethod.class

[image]

Comment: did you find a solution?

Comment: Then I changed the Stripe Plugin, then everything works fine.

**jitsi_meet: ^2.0.0**

**stripe_sdk: ^4.0.2**